# laid down his goose...used literally or figuratively?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following is the beginning paragraph of "The Social Triangle" by O Henry:

> At the stroke of six Ikey Snigglefritz **laid down his goose**.  Ikey was a tailor's apprentice.  Are there tailors' apprentices nowadays?

I wonder if the expression in bold "laid down his goose" should be interpreted literally or figuratively.

Comment: Please see Farlex: [tailor's goose](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Tailor%27s+goose).

Comment: @WeatherVane Please post this nice explanation as an answer.

Comment: Interestingly, although *etymologically* the tailor's goose has the same roots as the farmyard bird, native Anglophones clearly consider it to be a sufficiently "different" word today that the plural is ***tailor's gooses*** (as opposed to ***flock of geese*** for the "original" sense). But it's easy to find this definition in any half-way decent dictionary, so I think the question is Off Topic here.

Comment: Indeed I didn't post an answer because it can be found by looking for "tailor goose".

Answer (score 0):

A tailor's goose is the name given to heavy pointed iron.
This is a literal sentence.

Here are pictures of one.
https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01Dl5Co1erll4MYSx9PDlWCuww79A:1610488997232&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=tailors+goose&client=firefox-b-1-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBm-CEs5fuAhUEmVkKHet2D5QQjJkEegQIBRAB&biw=1500&bih=830&dpr=2